# Prove that $7 \mid abc(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)(c^3-a^3)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Let $a,b,c$ be positive integer. Prove that $abc(a^3-b^3)(b^3-c^3)(c^3-a^3)$ is divisible by $7$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hint: If $x\not\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, then $x^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}$.

Comment: You are welcome. It would be helpful if now and in the future you indicated what you had tried.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: care to elaborate on your hint a bit?

Comment: @jermenkoo:  If one or more of $a,b,c$ is divisible by $7$, our product is clearly divisible by $7$. If none of $a,b,c$ is divisible by $7$, then at least two of $a^3$, $b^3$, and $c^3$ are congruent to each other, since there are only two possible values of the cube modulo $7$.  Suppose for example that $b^3\equiv c^3\pmod{7}$. Then $b^3-c^3\equiv 0\pmod{7}$, meaning that $7$ divides $b^3-c^3$, and therefore $7$ divides the product.